# achartengine axes label issues

Tags: android, achartengine

The axes have been hidden by calling

```
setShowAxes(false);
```

But as you can see, there are still some small dash lines on the axes. Is there any way to hide these line as well?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those dashes drawing along with labels so it is impossible to get rid of them without clearing label names or changing source code. If it is okay to clearing labels you can use:

```
renderer.setShowLabels(false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to keep these text labels.